# How to handle language specific reserved words that occur in expression or variable names

Tags: java, coldfusion, antlr4

I've been working on this problem for about 4 hours now. Here is my ANTLR V4 grammar file which I've pared down to be simplest example possible.

```
grammar Cfscript;

component
    : (statement)*
    ;

statement
    : 'return' expression? ';'
    | statementExpression ';'
    ;

statementExpression
    : expression
    ;

expression
    : primary
    | expression '.' Identifier
    ;

primary
    : Identifier
    ;

Identifier
    : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
    ;

WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip 
    ;
```

My file contains

```
local.return;
```

When I attempt to parse this file entering at `component` I get the following error: `mismatched input 'return' expecting Identifier`. I cannot figure out why this error is occurring.

**Update**

If I understand correctly, this is because `return` is a reserved word in Java and that is why they have structured their grammar in that manner. In my language, Coldfusion Cfscript, `return` is valid as long as it is scoped: `local.return`, `variables.return`, `local["return"]`. This also holds true for `if`, `else`, `savecontent` and many other words, all of which are valid only inside scopes but not as the first term of a variable or expression: `if.blah = "something"` is invalid, but `blah.if = "something"` is valid. This means I will run into this same problem with every one of those terms as they will conflict with the parser rule that grabs them.

Synthesizing what Bart stated, is this a clean way to solve this problem?

```
grammar Cfscript;

component
    : (statement)*
    ;

statement
    : K_Return expression? ';'
    | expression ';'
    ;

expression
    : primary
    | expression '.' secondary
    ;

primary
    : Identifier
    ;

secondary
    : K_Return
    | K_If
    | K_Else
    | Identifier
    ;

K_Return : 'return' ;
K_If : 'if' ;
K_Else : 'else' ;

Identifier
    : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
    ;

WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip 
    ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding literal tokens inside parser rules, as you did with `'return'`, does *not* mean the lexer will match the string `"return"` as an `Identifier` inside the second alternative in your `expression` rule:

```
expression '.' Identifier
```

If you want to match `"return"` as a keyword *and* as an identifier in your language, you need to create a parser rule that matches both `Identifier`s and keywords:

```
expression
    : primary
    | expression '.' id
    ;

primary
    : id
    ;

id
    : Identifier
    | K_Return
    ;

// Better explicitly define them instead of litering keywords inside parser rules
K_Return
    : 'return'
    ;

Identifier
    : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
    ;
```

Comment: If that is the case how does the official Java grammar function?

Comment: @Nucleon, it doesn't allow `local.return;` as a valid expression.

Comment: As usual Bart, great answer, I updated my question based on what I learned from your answer, would you mind perusing it to see if it is a valid way of cleaning this up.

Comment: @Nucleon, yes, that looks okay.